# Can't running project after update Flutter to 1.20.3-stable

Tags: flutter

**Hello I have Problem in my project after upgrade flutter 1.20.3-stable ...I can't Know what the problem or why this happened by the way before updated  everything Working good ..any body help me ?**

**this is the Error is show**

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
               ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
 - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
      ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(description);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And this is the pubspce.yaml

```
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  fancy_on_boarding: ^1.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  get_mac: ^0.0.1
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  simple_connectivity: ^0.1.1
  jiffy: ^3.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.2+1
  time: ^1.3.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
  sweetalert: ^0.0.1
```

Comment: Did you tried 1.20.4 released yesterday?

Comment: No i tried 1.20.3 is the problem in version

Comment: sometimes bugs lands on stable channel, so, the best option is first thing: update. Also, post your "flutter doctor -v"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your dependencies uses `flutter_svg` which is where the problem is, see: https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/368

Run `flutter pub deps` to check the dependency tree which one is using `flutter_svg` and update it to the latest or file an issue there.

Comment: i tried run  flutter pub deps i'ts show me the flutter_svg  is using in fancy_on_boarding  package  and i was updated all dependency  That appear in it  to latest version  >>>but when run the problem is still there and the same error

Comment: @mohmmedali On the fancy_on_boarding github: https://github.com/xsahil03x/fancy_on_boarding/issues/35 a temporary fix is mentioned there as well